# VLC javascript API on IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, vlc

I'm trying to implement the [vlc web plugin](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin) for all browsers.

The best i could get from now , it's a fully working plugin on browsers like chrome and firefox and static plugin without any access to the javascript API in IE 9 and 8.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="span8" id="playerContainer">
    <!--[if IE]>
    <object
        classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" 
        id="vlcPlayer"
        name="vlcPlayer"
        events="True" width="800" height="450">
          <param name="Src" value="" />
          <param name="ShowDisplay" value="True" />
          <param name="AutoLoop" value="True" />
          <param name="AutoPlay" value="True" />
          <param name="Toolbar" value="false"></param>
    </object>
    <![endif]-->
</div>
```

here i include the plugin for IE this way because if i use a dynamic insert with javascript the plugin is forced to a width and height of 0px and is never been displayed.

**JS :**

```
function initVLC(width,height,stream)
{
    var embed   = "<div>Error loading plugin</div>";

    if(! $.browser.msie) {
        embed = '<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"'+
                        'id="vlcPlayer"'+
                        'toolbar ="false"'+
                        'autoplay="yes" loop="yes" width="'+width+'" height="'+height+'"'+
                        'target="" style="margin-bottom: 40px;" />';

        $('#playerContainer').html(embed);            
    }
    updateStream(stream);
}

function updateStream(stream)
{
    var vlc     = null;
    vlc = document.getElementById('vlcPlayer');
    vlc.playlist.stop();
    vlc.playlist.items.clear();
    vlc.playlist.add(stream);
    vlc.playlist.play();
}
```

On Chrome or firefox everything work fine.
On IE if i don't call `updateStream()` the plugin is displayed , but as soon as i try to use the javascript API , the plugin disapear (present in DOM but not displayed) and nothing happen.

When i debug with IE9 the vlc object seems to be ok and no errors are displayed :

[image: vlc object on IE9]

**How can i use the JS API with IE 9 and 8 to init and update the stream played by vlc ?**

Any working sample will be greatly appreciated

Note : I'm testing with vlc 2.0.5 on Win 7 64bits and my webpage have a html5 doctype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have switched to [FbVLC](http://code.google.com/p/fbvlc/) which is the vlc plugin using Firebreath.

It's working great and just require a fallback on classic vlc on non Windows client.